# Passing argument to filepath.Glob function in GoLang

Tags: go, filepath

I've been trying to get my head around with GoLang for few days and I am trying to make simple program which matches to certain files in certain directory. However I don't know how to pass variable to filepath.Glob function.

My attempt:

```
func ReadDirectory(srcDir string) {
    files, _ := filepath.Glob("[a-Z0-9]")
    fmt.Println(files)
}
```

This one prints well current directory where I am running the program. However I am looking for a way to list pass srcDir variable to it so I can find files from whatever directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just prefix the pattern with the directory:

```
files, _ := filepath.Glob(srcDir + "/[a-Z0-9]")
```

The [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) give this example:

> The pattern may describe hierarchical names such as `/usr/*/bin/ed` (assuming the Separator is `/`).